# Use of rnd in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The following code fails to compile due to the use of `rnd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.3}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {x};
    \draw [] (axis cs: 0,0)
      \foreach \i in {1,...,10} {
        -- ++ (axis direction cs: 0.2,rnd)
        };
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Why is this happening and how can it be rewritten to work as intended?

Comment: I believe that this has something to do with `axis direction cs`. Taking that out this compiles fine. Also, it is better to use `article` class and not `minimal`.  See [Why not use the minimal class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-not-use-the-minimal-class).

Comment: @PeterGrill by removing ``axis direction cs`` it seems to compile, but I can't see any drawings however!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably due to the coordinate parsing as `rnd` is not recognized as a math function but as a non-number instead. Bracing it or other syntax tricks might work but it's best to avoid them for such simple constructions.

Here is one option by removing the math parsing from the coordinate parsing. `\pgfextra` is used to pause the parsing and do some additional operations.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {x};
    \draw [] (axis cs: 0,0)
      \foreach \i in {1,...,10} {\pgfextra{\pgfmathparse{rnd}}
        -- ++ (axis direction cs: 0.2,\pgfmathresult)
        };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]